# Нужна ли запятая после "присоединиться к Лиге"?

Tags: запятые

Пос­ле сог­ла­сия Ми­дории при­со­еди­нить­ся к Ли­ге прош­ло нес­коль­ко дней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.
Предложение простое, в нём обстоятельство выражено существительным с предлогом "после". Здесь нет обстоятельства в виде деепричастного оборота, сравнительного оборота или уточнения.

Про обособление обстоятельств можно почитать здесь: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177